# Custom itemize with extra parameters for items

Tags: environments, itemize, parameters

I am currently working on a document class for creating worksheets for school in which I want to include a `multiplechoice` environment. For this I basically used the `itemize` environment and changed the default bullet to a big square drawn with tikz. I also want to be able to easily create solutions for these worksheets and so I introduced a boolean `solution` which determines if the correct answers are ticked or not.

Now my problem is how to define which ansers are correct and which ones are not. In the end I want this to look something like this:

```
\begin{multiplechoice}
    \item[correct] Correct answer
    \item Incorrect answer
\end{multiplechoice}
```

But I am not sure how to add this parameter to the items. So far, this is what the `multiplechoice` environment looks like:

```
\newenvironment{multiplechoice}{
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{
        \tikz[baseline=-0.3em]{
            \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (0.2, 0.2);
            \ifsolution
                \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, -0.2) -- (0.2, 0.2);
                \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, 0.2) -- (0.2, -0.2);
            \fi
        }
    }

    \itemize
    \bgroup
}{
    \egroup
    \enditemize
}
```

Currently, every anser will be ticked if `solution` is true.

Comment: I would probably prefer an input syntax like `\choice` / `\choice*` over `\item` / `\item[Correct]`. Are you using the "expl" LaTeX3 macro formats at all?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau First of all, thank you very much for your quick answer! I must admit that I am fairly new to TeX and LaTeX, so I did not know about the * sytanx, but I like it more than the [\correct] way. I am also not sure what you mean with "expl" LaTeX3 macro formats, nor do I know if I am using them...

Comment: You are welcome. The `*` modifier is used on many LaTeX commands (but not on `\item`). The "expl" (experimental) definitions provide a cleaner syntax for defining such "star" commands, but no matter--the "messy" version of `\choice` is still easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `\item` as requested, with only a tiny change from the question: Instead of `[correct]`, use `[\correct]`. That change makes the solution much easier, since it matches the regular optional parameter that `\item` always takes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifsolution

\newcommand{\choicebox}{%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.3em]{%
       \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (0.2, 0.2);
    }%
}
\newcommand{\correct}{%
    \ifsolution
        \tikz[baseline=-0.3em]{%
            \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (0.2, 0.2);
            \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, -0.2) -- (0.2, 0.2);
            \draw[black, thick] (-0.2, 0.2) -- (0.2, -0.2);
        }%
    \else
        \choicebox
    \fi
}

\newenvironment{multiplechoice}{%
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\choicebox}%
    \itemize
}{%
    \enditemize
}
% The previous \bgroup and \egroup were bad.

\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}
    \item[\correct] Correct answer
    \item Incorrect answer
\end{multiplechoice}

\solutiontrue


\begin{multiplechoice}
    \item[\correct] Correct answer
    \item Incorrect answer
\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

I would probably prefer to use an input syntax of `\choice` and `\choice*`, and a definition of `\choice` could be layered over the solution with `\item`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\choice{\@ifstar{\item[\correct]}{\item}}
\makeatother
```